# PHP and MYSQL system (plus HTML,CSS&JS)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I went for a 4 month degree php & mysql classes and we are almost done with them, and they ask us to make a system that you could add, erase, and modify the data that the user can put in it (but is harder than that, I have to do it as they said to me, with their parameters and etc.. ), the thing is that i don't know from where i have to start (I'm doing the HTML so the "user" can use the system easily, but when it comes to do the php, JS and MYSQL part im broke), and I hope there's someone here that could help me. I'm not asking for someone to do it for me, that's not my intention, but i really appreciate if someone could lend me a hand so i can dig in more and more in this php world.
Bye!

PS: If someone wants to help me, we can chat by skype, or something like that, because my English is not that good, and by text-post maybe you wont understand what i want to mean.

Comment: What did you learn in those 4 months?

Comment: @Daan I learned too much things in a short amount of time (the degree was for 3 days a week, 2 hours each day) so my head has a bunch of information but im too confused to use it correctly, because they teached us from the begining, i mean, they teached us HTML from the basics, JS from the basics, PHP from the basics and a bit of MYSQL just the enough to us to create a database, tables, and columns.
I already have much of the HTML and JS parts done, but at the php part im confused, i know what i want to do, but i dont know how to code it..

Answer (score 2):

#### 1 - Agree on a design pattern

Having a suitable and elegant design pattern will help improve your development, and in most instances, make it much easier - as the foundations will be set.

- [Design patterns](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)

#### 2 - Adopt version control

A good platform is Git. Specifically [GitLab](http://gitlabhq.com) or [GitHub](http://gitlab.com). Adopting version control will improve your development, and help you keep track of everything you do, building a story.

#### 3 - Don't use outdated technology

Please don't use the old [MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) database extention. Instead, adopt [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO-MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Using the newer technology will make your application much more secure against SQL injections... [See full argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/3000179)

#### 4 - Be smart

Design your database in to be smart. [Normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data, and structure your queries nicely - use stored procedures where neccessary, and transactional queries.

When using Javascript within your application, it may be worth while to look into some libraries. The most popular (IIRC) is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

#### 5 - Use a framework

Judging from your question, it may be easier for you to adopt a framework, where help is available.

- [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)
- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/)
- ... There are more. Choose the best one for you.

Also, have a read of [PHPTheRightWay](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

Comment: I'd really apreciate what u answered here.
But talking about they gave me the tools i have to use to do this, so i have to do it with what they gave me, i cannot use anything apart of that, but i really apreciate your answer.
Have a nice day!